# Converting a List of Pandas Series to a single Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

I am using `statsmodels.api` on my data set. I have a list of panda series. The panda series has key value pairs. The keys are the names of the columns and the values contain the data. But, I have a list of series where the keys (column names) are repeated. I want to save all of the values from the list of  pandas series to a single dataframe where the column names are the keys of the panda series. All of the series in the list have the same keys. I want to save them as a single data frame so that I can export the dataframe as a CSV. Any idea how I can save the keys as my column names of the df and then have the values fill the rest of the information.

Each series in the list returns something like this:

```
index 0 of the list: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

height     23
weight     10
size       45
amount      9 

index 1 of the list: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

height     11
weight     99
size       25
amount     410 

index 2 of the list: <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

height     3
weight     0
size       115
amount     92
```

I would like to be able to read a dataframe such that these values are saved as the following:

```
DataFrame:

height   weight   size   amount
  23       10      45      9
  11       11      25      410
   3        3      115     92
```

Comment: check with pd.concat(l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
pd.DataFrame(data=your_list_of_series)
```

When creating a new DataFrame, pandas will accept a list of series for the data argument. The indices of your series will become the column names of the DataFrame.

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient way, but this does the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

series_list =[  pd.Series({ 'height':     23,
                        'weight':     10,
                        'size':       45,
                        'amount':      9
                      }),
            pd.Series({ 'height':     11,
                        'weight':     99,
                        'size':       25,
                        'amount':      410
                     }),

            pd.Series({ 'height':     3,
                        'weight':     0,
                        'size':       115,
                        'amount':      92
                     })
        ]

pd.DataFrame( [series.to_dict() for series in series_list] )
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the duplicate keys that are created. I only need one set of keys with a list of values, just like how an excel file would look.

Comment: My solution produces unique indicies. DataFrame's don't have keys, but the analogy is an index.

Comment: It's also identical to the 2 posted after mine, but the accepted one is general instead of answering your specific case, which is cool i guess

Answer (score 1):

Did you try just calling `pd.DataFrame()` on the list of series? That should just work.

```
import pandas as pd

series_list = [
    pd.Series({
            'height': 23,
            'weight': 10,
            'size': 45,
            'amount': 9
        }),
        pd.Series({
            'height': 11,
            'weight': 99,
            'size': 25,
            'amount': 410
        }),
        pd.Series({
            'height': 3,
            'weight': 0,
            'size': 115,
            'amount': 92
        })
    ]
df = pd.DataFrame(series_list)
print(df)
df.to_csv('path/to/save/foo.csv')
```

Output:

```
   height  weight  size  amount
0      23      10    45       9
1      11      99    25     410
2       3       0   115      92
```